# Heroku deployment error: The requested API endpoint was not found

Tags: django, git, python-3.x, heroku

I have the worked app (Availible here [tandtpartners.herokuapp.com](https://tandtpartners.herokuapp.com))
But I've got the 
 `remote: !       The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP verb (i.e. GET vs. POST), and did you specify your intended version with the Accept header?`
 error while trying to deploy the app again.

Even when I cloned this app to another folder and added some `!` to `index.html`, I received the same error.

```
C:\heroku\2\tandtpartners>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'heroku/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   hello/templates/index.html


C:\heroku\2\tandtpartners>git commit -m "Changed only index html"
[master 8a56e0d] Changed only index html
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

C:\heroku\2\tandtpartners>git commit -m "Changed only index html"
[master 8a56e0d] Changed only index html
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

C:\heroku\2\tandtpartners>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 432 bytes | 432.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: !       The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP verb (i.e. `GET` vs. `POST`), and did you specify your intended version with the `Accept` header?
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/tandtpartners.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/tandtpartners.git'
```

What can I do with that?

Comment: We might need to contact Heroku support, I'm having the same error when I try to deploy with [dpl](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl).

Comment: Yes. we need to contact support. I am also getting the same error since last 1 hour only.

Comment: Yeah, since last couple of hours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924984/error-in-deploying-code-on-heroku

Comment: I tried with NodeJS, it's same from nodejs as well. I guess it is an internal Heroku server error. Maybe they'd recognize the bug and auto-fix in an hour or two, as the community would have been reported by now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Heroku status page](https://status.heroku.com/)

> API Errors for Free Accounts
>
> We are investigating reports of increased API errors. This affects a
>   number of actions on the platform, including deploys, for users
>   without a credit card associated with their account. We will update
>   here shortly.

(For future users: This answer is valid only for a short period of time, if you have the same issue, maybe you should give a look at https://status.heroku.com/)

Answer (score 1):

API Errors for Free Accounts

Tools 0 MINUTES
ACTIVITY

Issue

We are investigating reports of increased API errors. This affects a number of actions on the platform, including deploys, for users without a credit card associated with their account. We will update here shortly.
POSTED 4 MINUTES AGO, FEB 22, 2018 10:47 UTC

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1404

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:  API Errors for Free Accounts.

A change causing the issue was discovered and a fix has been deployed. This affected application builds for users without a credit card between 08:41 UTC and 11:00 UTC.

This issue is now resolved.

The most recent information is available at: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1404

Comment: You can edit your answer below, no need to post duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug caught and fixed.
As per heroku https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1404

Answer (score 0):

1. check if heroku is added as remote: git remote -v
   you should see something like this:

heroku    https://git.heroku.com/yourapp.git (fetch)  AND
heroku    https://git.heroku.com/yourapp.git (push)

2. if there is none then set the remote - git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:MyApp.git (in old git versions ) or heroku git:remote -a git@heroku.com:MyApp.git (in new version of git)
3. git push heroku master (old git)
   git push heroku main (new git )