# Error in deploying code on heroku

Tags: heroku

I have a java script code in git hub and I was deploying it many many times on heroku during the last month and I had no problem.Today, when I wanted to deploy the exact same code on heroku, I've got the following error:

```
The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP verb (i.e. `GET` vs. `POST`), and did you specify your intended version with the `Accept` header?
```

Does anybody know why I encountered this error and what should I do to solve it?

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924284/heroku-python-3-6-3-django-app-deployment-error-the-requested-api-endpoint-wa

Comment: same problem here as well. It's happening from a couple of hours I guess. I am trying to deploy the NodeJS code. It was working well last night with Github auto Deploy. But not now. I also tried deleting the dyno and recreating and pushing. Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same error since today, even though I've been able to deploy my java app before.
There might be something wrong on heroku's end.

I made a ticket and I'll try to update you on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and when I was looking for to create a ticket I found this support notification about this issue now, it's an internal error in Heroku.

[Check this link](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1404)

> We are investigating reports of increased API errors. This affects a number of actions on the platform, including deploys, for users without a credit card associated with their account. We will update here shortly.