# NodeJS heroku deployment error for all apps on my machine: The requested API endpoint was not found

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, web-deployment, heroku-cli

I was able to deploy successfully to Heroku just a few hours before these errors happen. Basically, when this happened to one of my apps that I've been working on, I went back and tried deploying my previous apps to heroku, and all attempts gave me the same error. This is the error I copied off my terminal.

$ git push heroku master Counting objects: 4, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads. Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done. Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 339 bytes | 339.00 KiB/s, done. Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: Compressing source files... done. remote: Building source: remote:  remote: !    The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP verb (i.e. `GET` vs. `POST`), and did you specify your intended version with the `Accept` header? remote:  To https://git.heroku.com/hidden-forest-99088.git  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hidden-forest-99088.git'

My heroku-cli is up to date. In fact, I've reinstalled it to no avail. I've tried cloning a project and deploying. I've tried creating a brand new project to deploy. And I've scoured google for solutions and tried whatever solutions others have found successful, such as reseting the buildpack on heroku. Everything failed. Also, there's no log about my attempts to deploy on the heroku website.

I'm at my wits ends. Please help.

Comment: There is something wrong on heroku's side. People have been seeing this error since last hour. I am also unable to push to heroku. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924284/heroku-python-3-6-3-django-app-deployment-error-the-requested-api-endpoint-wa

Comment: @qnsi thanks! that's a relief. i hope this gets resolved soon.